# VS Code suggestion attribute of Django class based view

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

[vscode django classbased view suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ipx4z.jpg)

Hello Experts,

I have been creating djagno project on vscode as per front screen(windows 10) in the picture and vscode helped me to write correct attribute of the class based view with suggesoin (Ex. context_object_name)

I have shifted to windows 11 as per the second screen in the back. I am not getting suggesion of the attribute of Djanngo's class based view and I would like to see it there same as front screen in the picture. Can anyone help me with the query?

Thanks in advance for ones time and efforts to answer my query.

Comment: Can you at least post a screenshot, instead of a picture of your screen?